# New Workout Plan Causes Soreness

Tags: workout-routines, soreness, p90x

I'm in the second week of trying P90X and after I do the plyo x workout I can barely walk afterwards. This last 3-4 days.
I have a physically demanding job and spend 8-10 hours a day at work and use a elliptical machine every other day as well. I was hoping to space out the extreme factor of P90 by adding the elliptical in there but it backfired.

Is this normal? Any suggestions as whats going wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your physically demanding job? It sounds normal in the sense that adding P90X to whatever you normally do would cause soreness, as I've done similar things myself and am very active. It may be that you haven't grown accustomed to the new workout yet.

Comment: I've done plyo-style aerobic workouts before that made it painful to get up and down off the toilet :( For the record, I think this means you are doing it RIGHT. Cut out the elliptical for now, I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The soreness is a result of you working your muscles in ways they are not used to. The plyo X on P90X is intense, and I felt the same way afterward.

I would say if your job requires you to climb ladders or something strenuous like that, I would say save your plyo routine for the weekend or a day where you don't have to work immediately the next day. P90X is an all-inclusive workout. You're getting HIIT, strength training and warm-ups/cooldowns. You don't really NEED the elliptical, as it's probably not doing much but burning some extra calories.

If you're really trying to get better at the P90X thing, I would drop the elliptical and incorporate some stretching, some lunges, some core work, maybe some shoulder work, until the plyo circuit gets easier. AND IT WILL GET EASIER. It takes consistency, so keep trying, don't give up!